# How do I create a data structure that will conform to a certain JSON representation after encoding?

Tags: json, perl

I am new to Perl and I need to encode to JSON. This is the JSON code:

```
{
    "fields": {
        "project": {
            "key": "ABC"
        },
        "summary": "REST TESTING",
        "description": "Creating of an issue using project keys and issue type names using the REST API",
        "issuetype": {
            "name": "Bug"
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me with the Perl code?

Comment: Please provide more details. What problem are you having with the Perl code?

Comment: The perl structure that should be encoded to JSON

Comment: What problem are you having with it? It should be arrays and hashes, common in all perl scripts.

Comment: It may be yes common but this is my first time to write Perl script,,, Sorry

Comment: then you need to learn how to use perl. We can't teach you perl this way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Perl [JSON](https://metacpan.org/module/MAKAMAKA/JSON-2.59/lib/JSON.pm) module will take a complex Perl data structure and encode it into a JSON textbased structure.

You said *I am new to Perl*. As you've probably discovered, Perl's basic data structures only refer to individual bits of data. A *scalar* (`$foo`) encodes a single piece of data. *Arrays* (`@foo`) and hashes (`%foo`) encode lists of single bits of data. None of these structures can capture the complexity of a JSON (or XML or YAML or Marshal) data structure.

However, Perl has something called references that allow you to have things such as *hashes* of *hashes* or *arrays* of *arrays* or *hashes* of *arrays*, etc. You need to understand these complex structures in order to be able to encode and decode JSON structures.

Fortunately, Perl has a built in tutorial in references in its Perldocs. If you are not familiar with references, take the [Tutorial](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html). Then, you can start working on encoding our JSON structures.

Here's a program that encodes the exact structure in your post:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw(say);

use JSON;
use Data::Dumper;

my $json_data_ref = {};
$json_data_ref->{fields}->{project}->{key} = "ABC";
$json_data_ref->{fields}->{summary} = "REST TESTING";
$json_data_ref->{fields}->{description} = "Creating of an issue project keys and issue "
    . "type names using the REST API";
$json_data_ref->{fields}->{issuetype}->{name} = "Bug";
$json_data_ref->{fields}->{fixedVersions}->[0]->{id} = "1223";

my $json_text = to_json ( $json_data_ref, { pretty => 1 } );

say $json_text;
```

The output is:

```
{
   "fields" : {
      "summary" : "REST TESTING",
      "project" : {
          "key" : "ABC"
      },
      "description" : "Creating of an issue project keys and issue type names using the REST API",
       "issuetype" : {
       "name" : "Bug"
      }
       "FixedVersions" : [
           { "id: "1223" }
       ]
   }
}
```

Comment: thanks alot that is exactly what i want needed

Comment: I am sorry, can you help me add this as a field item as summary , it is like something like this: ' "FixVerion" : [ { "id" = "1233" } ] '

Comment: See above. I made the change in my post.

Comment: I am really thankful for you,,, thanks alot...

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Perl `JSON` module](http://p3rl.org/JSON) on CPAN. That will handle all the encoding/decoding and you just need to manage your Perl structures appropriately.

Comment: The problem is in handling the Perl structres